# Make incoming call in Android emulator without command code

Tags: android, android-emulator, phone-call

I'm trying to develop a small app that will be registered on `PhoneStateListener` and do some magic over incoming and outgoing calls monitor. For debugging purposes, I need to trigger `onCallStateChanged(...)` event from outside of phone, not perform real incoming voice call.

Is it possible to do this somehow with sending phone number to debugged app without command line code?

Comment: DDMS -> Emulator Control -> Telephony Actions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create one more emulator on avd machine. You can find the emulator number from top of the emulator. Eg. 5554 this number is like phone number you can enter the emulator this number(5554 or 5556 or somting) and make a incoming call.

enjoy ...

Comment: May I trigger incoming call for debug with specific number?

Comment: it worked in the first install, but in another installation it does not work any more. strange.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow Go to Window ===> Open Perspective & choose DDMS

In DDMS click on Emulator Control then select Voice and write number of another emulator on which You want to call. and then click on call .

You can find another emulator number from top of the emulator.

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDMS perspective in eclipse for initiating dummy calls , message etc

You can see DDMS perspective on top right corner if you do not see it

Go to Window ===> Open Perspective & choose DDMS

Answer (score 0):

Try one more emulator. You can find the emulator number from top of the emulator. Eg. 5556