# How to make a incoming call on emulator not use telnet

Tags: android, telnet

As we know, we can make an incoming call or send sms to emulator by telnet command.

But I need make an incoming call on android side. Because telnet is just used for login in android side,so I think there must be a way to execute command on android side.

Is there anyone know how to make it?

Comment: You can call to one emulator using its port number from another emulator.

Answer (score 0):

From : [Make incoming call in Android emulator without command code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460621/how-to-make-incoming-call-in-android-emulator-without-commad-code)

1. Create a second emulator. Use the first emulator to call the second emulator. Emulator's number is the port number. 5554, 5556 etc.
2. Just follow Go to Window ===> Open Perspective & choose DDMS
   In DDMS click on Emulator Control, then select Voice. Enter number of the emulator on which you want to make the call. and then click on call.